# Erro de JSON no PHP : SyntaxError: JSON.parse!

Tags: php, json, google, maps

Estou com um probleminha ao preencher o Google Maps com alguns marcadores, vindo de um PHP (json).

Quando abro o browser, aparece o erro:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Código PHP:

```
<?
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

   include 'conn-login.php';

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){

     $sql = "SELECT id, lat, lng, endereco, especie, raca, obs, data, id_cadastro FROM mapa";
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($id, $lat, $lng, $endereco, $especie, $raca, $obs, $data, $id_cadastro);
     $stmt->store_result();


   if($stmt->num_rows <= 0){

       $var = Array(
         'status' => 'ERRO',
         'msg' => 'Nenhum dado encontrado'
       );

     } else {

       while ($ln = $stmt->fetch()){

         $var = Array(
           'status' => 'OK',
           'id' => $id,
           'lat' => $lat,
           'lng' => $lng,
           'endereco' => $endereco,
           'especie' => $especie,
           'raca' => $raca,
           'obs' => $obs,
           'data' => $data,
           'id_cadastro' => $id_cadastro
         );

       };
     };

       echo json_encode($var);
       //var_dump($var);
       exit;


   }

   $stmt->close(); 

   ?>
```

E com esse erro, os Google Maps não consegue puxar as informações. Alguém poderia me ajudar onde estou errando?

Comment: Esse erro é retornado pelo JavaScript ou pelo próprio PHP?

Comment: A única coisa fora do lugar que notei fo `$stmt->close(); ` essa linha deve estar dentro do bloco `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){` se não vai gerar erro já que a conexão só é aberta se entrar no if, se não entrar não existe uma válida. Remova também os `;` após as chaves.

Comment: Existem acentos?

Comment: Você retorna quantos dados?

Comment: @CamiloSilva é retornado quando abro a página no browser. Quando faço um get no arquivo, não retorna nada.

Comment: @lazyFox apenas espaços.

Comment: @rray removi já. obrigado!

Comment: @adventistaam todos os 9 dados.

Comment: Consegui resolver. O arquivo .php meu deve estar com algum bug. Peguei um mais novo e reformulei para o que quero e deu certo!